# Would I see a mushroom cloud if I nuke the sun corona?

Tags: temperature, sun, explosions

The sun corona can reach an extremely high temperature at least a few million degree, say if the temperature of the explosion of a nuclear bomb is roughly equal to the temperature of the corona then would a mushroom cloud forms?

p.s: I know that it is extremely difficult to land a hit on the Sun from Earth and even so everything would simply vaporize before then, but I really like to find out if it is possible to grow a mushroom cloud on the corona.

Comment: Have you been watching [Sunshine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448134/)?

Comment: "Extremely difficult" is a relative judgement. 
 If they can afford to do this, then they could afford to get four million miles closer if they wanted to:  http://earthsky.org/space/send-your-name-to-sun-solar-probe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mushroom clouds happen because the hot gas released by an explosion is buoyant compared to the surrounding colder atmosphere, since it has lower density. Were an explosion happen in an atmosphere of equal temperature I assume one could still get a [Rayleigh-Taylor instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Taylor_instability) due to lower density, but it would be far less pronounced.

In the corona the gas is a charged plasma, so the dynamics is going to be very different. The mean-free path of fast particles is very long, so the explosion is going to spread out, and the actual shape will be due to magnetohydrodynamic flows. As far as I know, nobody has studied what it would be shaped like, but it is very doubtful you would get a mushroom cloud. A mushroom cloud would for instance snag a lot of magnetic field lines that would act back on it, likely preventing it from forming a toroidal core and the characteristic mushroom shape. My guess is that you get something like a coronal mass ejection, a blob of plasma that flows outwards.

Comment: A nuclear explosion might not release as much hot gas as you think.  Most of the matter in a nuclear fireball is _air_ that has been heated to incandescence by the radiation.

Comment: @jameslarge - Yes, that is true. Nuclear explosions in space are suprisingly wimpy. In this case there will not even be an EMP since the surroundings are already pretty ionized.